# Does Jude 1:13 refer to literal planets or fallen angels?

Tags: angels, jude, demons, 1-enoch

> Raging waves of the sea, foaming out their own shame; wandering stars,
>   to whom is reserved the blackness of darkness for ever.

Compare this to the book of Enoch, which Jude apparently considered canon:

> 18:12 And beyond that abyss I saw a place which had no firmament of the
>   heaven above, and no firmly founded earth beneath it: there was no
>   water upon it, and no birds, but it was a waste and horrible place.
>   13. I saw there seven stars like great burning mountains, and to me, when I inquired regarding them, 14. The angel said: 'This place is the
>   end of heaven and earth: this has become a prison for the stars and
>   the host of heaven.

Comment: The fact that some words are similar does not necessitate that Jude knew about, or approved of, the other writing. That is supposition. The whole passage, in context, refers to (verse 4) 'certain men crept in unawares'.

Comment: I'm not understanding how to get to either planets or angels from that text. Nowhere does either of these words appear in that verse, however I am aware of the connection between the morning/day star and Satan however...

Answer (score 4):

> **Jude 1:8-13 (DRB)** In like manner **these men** also defile the flesh, and despise dominion, and blaspheme majesty. 9 When Michael the archangel, disputing with the devil, contended about the body of Moses, he durst not bring against him the judgment of railing speech, but said: The Lord command thee. 10 **But these men** blaspheme whatever things they know not: and what things soever they naturally know, like dumb beasts, in these they are corrupted. 11 Woe unto them, for they have gone in the way of Cain: and after the error of Balaam they have for reward poured out themselves, and have perished in the contradiction of Core.
>
> 12 **These** are spots in [your love-feasts], feasting together without fear, feeding themselves, clouds without water, which are carried about by winds, trees of the autumn, unfruitful, twice dead, plucked up by the roots, 13 Raging waves of the sea, foaming out their own confusion; wandering stars, to whom the storm of darkness is reserved for ever. 14 Now **of these** Enoch also, the seventh from Adam, prophesied...

This portion of Jude concerns wolves among the sheep, as it were (*Mt 7:15; 10:16*), or chaff among the wheat (*Mt 3:12; 13:25*), and **not angelic beings** of either the just or fallen kind. He mentions their inconspicuous presence at their intimate Christian meals of communion, called the *Agape*, or *Love-Feast* (*v. 12*).<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>**Footnotes**</sup>

<sup>1 An communal meal the early church seems to have had (usually) with but distinct from the Eucharist, as a symbol of Christian unity (cf. *Acts 4:32*)</sup>